# How to build a query that extracts all the current contracts owned by a user through transaction history

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm setting up a script that needs to extract all current contracts owned by a user through transaction history.

Here's the transaction table and some test data:

```
CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sender_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `recipient_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `contract_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `sender_id` (`sender_id`,`contract_id`,`tokens`),
  KEY `recipient_id` (`recipient_id`,`contract_id`,`tokens`)
);

INSERT INTO `transaction` VALUES 
(1,10,20,1,'2019-01-20 15:41:47'),
(2,10,20,2,'2019-01-20 15:41:47'),
(3,30,10,1,'2019-01-20 15:41:47'),
(4,30,10,3,'2019-01-20 15:41:47'),
(5,20,10,2,'2019-01-20 15:41:47');
```

As output i would like an array with all contract id's for a given user.

Output of the query for user id = 10:

```
+-------------+
| contract_id |
+-------------+
|           1 |
+-------------+
|           2 |
+-------------+
|           3 |
+-------------+
```

This is the current code that I have to achieve this. However, it would be nice if it would be one query.

```
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT contract_id
    FROM transaction
    WHERE tokens IS NULL
    ORDER BY created_on DESC';

$statement = $this->entityManager
    ->getConnection()
    ->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$contracts = [];

foreach ($statement->fetchAll() as $row) {
    $query = 'SELECT *
        FROM transaction
        WHERE contract_id = :contract
        AND tokens IS NULL
        ORDER BY created_on DESC';

    $statement = $this->entityManager
        ->getConnection()
        ->prepare($query);

    $statement->execute([
        'contract' => $row['contract_id']
    ]);

    $result = $statement->fetch();

    if ((int) $result['recipient_id'] !== $user->getId()) {
        continue;
    }

    $contracts[] = $result['contract_id'];
}

return $contracts;
```

Comment: What exactly is your difficulty? What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Im having troubles with the sender_id and recipient_id part. I have to create a query that follows both sender and recipient to figure out who owns a certain contract or contracts. I've tried to use CROSS JOIN, but that's where it ends for me.

Comment: Might be wrong test data because you only have contract_id 1.. Besides you should provide a text formatted excepted results so we can verivy our query.

Comment: I've updated the test data and provided a text formatted result.

Comment: so the user id is matched against `recipient_id`, `sender_id` or both?

Comment: user_id in this case is recipient_id. Probably solvable by taking the last transaction of every contract that has the given user as recipient.

Answer (score 1):

Take the minimal possible answer, use `DISTINCT` to prevent duplicates in the output. `ORDER BY` is optional.

```
SELECT DISTINCT contract_id
FROM transactions
WHERE recipient_id = :id
ORDER BY contract_id
```

Your `recipient_id` index will help will this query.

Comment: I changed the description with the code that I've made to achief this. Perhaps this gives a better explanation about what it should do.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you didn't give information as to who the contract owner is based on your database fields. Couldn't tell if it was sender_id or recipient_id. Your question was also a little vague in that I couldn't work out if you wanted numerous associative arrays based on the data.

```
SELECT contract_id
FROM transactions
WHERE sender_id = ?
GROUP BY contract_id, created_on DESC
```

Please do remember to escape your input values.